# Flutter built-in fonts

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts, flutter-dependencies

I want to use some fonts in flutter that I'm not sure if their already comes with flutter.
What are the built-in fonts that come with flutter without a need to import them as a custom font?

Answer (score 1):

I couldnt find a place to browse build in fonts but I found a recomended package that contains 1k+ fonts called [google_fonts](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts) that allowes you to use fonts without need to specify them in `pubspec.yaml` file (because thats what you try to avoid right?). 
After importing this package you can very easly browse all the fonts you gained access to at [Google Fonts Site](https://fonts.google.com/).

Comment: I am currently using this package but the fonts takes time to load. I want to know if it is necessary or not for some fonts.